# When replacing characters in a variable, I get this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

So this is my code:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args, Discord) => {
  args = args.replace(/&/g, "").trim() || "+";
```

But I get this error

```
args.replace is not a function
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably args isnt a string.

Comment: Check the type of args, may be it's not string object `console.log(typeof(args));`

Also, check if `args` is string then is it empty ?

Comment: @OmSao That didn't work either: ```console.log(typeOf(args));
              ^

ReferenceError: typeOf is not defined```

Comment: @Anidox: Please try `console.log(typeof(args));` it will tell you what object type `args` is. Also as per general convention: `args` is array of arguments, so please check if it's an array then you need to execute like `args[<index>].replace....` as suggested in answer by D.Simon

Answer (score 1):

Args is most likely not a string but an array. You can iterate over the array with a for loop and do your replacing stuff there.

```
for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    args[i] = args[i].replace(/&/g, "").trim() || "+";
}
```

Comment: How is it different then what OP is trying?

Comment: @OmSao args[i] is a string while args is an array, so the replace function doesn't throw the error.

Comment: @D.Simon It simply does nothing different than if it wasn't there